# How can I put an instance of a not-yet-defined class in a Python class variable?

Tags: python, class, attributes

I have two classes, which I'll call ClassA and ClassB in this example. I'd like to have a class variable in ClassA which creates instances of ClassA and ClassB, as shown in the example below:

```
class ClassA:
    CLASSVAR=ClassA(ClassB())
    def __init__(self,arg):
        pass
class ClassB:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

However, when I try to do this, I get the following error: `NameError: name 'ClassA' is not defined`.

Is it possible to get a class variable like `CLASSVAR` which creates instances of `ClassA` and `ClassB` without getting this error?

Here's why I want to do this:

I'm using classes to represent certain mathematical functions. Each instance of a function class will have arguments stored as instance variables, which consist of other expressions. The functions have a _deriv method, which takes the derivative of the entire expression. For functions of one variable, it is easiest to do this using the chain rule, so I have a OneInput class that they inherit from.

This OneInput class has a _deriv method which needs to know the derivative of the function which inherits from it when it is taken by itself (for example, for the function Reciprocal, this would be -1/x^2). I'm trying to store this as a class variable of each function which inherits from OneInput, but I can't do this since the derivative of a function sometimes includes that function (for example, the derivitive of the Reciprocal function 1/x includes the Reciprocal of x^2).

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @InSync Good point; I edited my post above to add a bit more context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to assign it after creating the classes:

```
class ClassA:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg
class ClassB:
    pass
ClassA.CLASSVAR = ClassA(ClassB())
```

If you want to appease mypy, you can provide an annotation for the class variable:

```
from typing import ClassVar

class ClassA:
    CLASSVAR: ClassVar['ClassA']
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg
class ClassB:
    pass
ClassA.CLASSVAR = ClassA(ClassB())
```